# Getting error while using Tweepy IDE in Python?

Tags: python, tweepy

It's just a simple program to download timeline tweet,I am calling my keys and then after authentication redirect it to download my tweet.

```
import tweepy
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('My consumer key', 'My consumer secret')
auth.set_access_token('My access token', 'My access token secret')
api = tweepy.API(auth)
public_tweets = api.home_timeline()
for tweet in public_tweets:
    print (tweet.text)
```

But when I Execute this module, I get Error as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/tweepy1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tweepy
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\tweepy-3.4.0-py3.4.egg\tweepy\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from tweepy.models import Status, User, DirectMessage, Friendship, SavedSearch, SearchResults, ModelFactory, Category
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\tweepy-3.4.0-py3.4.egg\tweepy\models.py", line 7, in <module>
    from tweepy.utils import parse_datetime, parse_html_value, parse_a_href
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\tweepy-3.4.0-py3.4.egg\tweepy\utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    import six
ImportError: No module named 'six'
```

I am really struck , I can't make out where I went wrong . I tried to find about this error but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem you don't have the essential `six` library for `tweepy`. `tweepy` does need several dependencies, you can check [here](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/requirements.txt) for more details.

You can install `six` using

```
pip install six
```

or

```
easy_install six
```

or you can download the **binary** package from Christoph Gohlke's site and install it

```
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#six
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @HassanQamar You can check [here](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html) for more details of using pip. Or you can just press "win+r" and type "cmd" to go to the terminal, and then type the code in my answer.

Comment: Just a last question, Tweepy is package , and six is a file, I installed Tweepy through cmd as "setup.py install" ,  and it worked . But this file I divert cmd directories but it will show error , saying pip is not recongnizable. I know these queries are very basic but I can't help it .

Comment: @HassanQamar Both `Tweepy` and `six` are python libraries, even through it seems like a file. According to tweepy's [requirements](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/requirements.txt), tweepy is built based on six, that's why you need to install six.

Comment: Thankyou very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You must install `six` in order to use tweepy. Install it using pip as,

```
pip install six
```

In case if you are using virtualenv, you can check `six` is installed or not in virtualenv using ,

```
pip freeze
```

Comment: Sorry I am new to python, I didn't get exactly how to install six, I downloaded it from Github, a 10kb file , then how to proceed? Help will be really appreciated

Comment: Just write to your console as pip install six and press enter.